# Python - Possible loop function to track a person's movement throughout time and group it with others?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My problem is, I'd like to track IDs throughout time, seeing where they go next and group them with others for their first location point. I am using excel at the moment to sort by date and ID. When sorted by date, I know where individual people went for their first visit to a location. If I then remove the first instances of those IDs, I am left with the next place they go. I then remove those instances and so on and so on.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
ID  Location    Date
76  School      4/12/2018
111 Post Office 4/15/2018
112 School      4/10/2018
324 School      2/10/2018
22  Library     4/12/2018
19  Library     4/13/2028
17  Post Office 5/11/2018
76  Library     4/25/2018
19  Library     4/27/2019
112 School      3/23/2018
76  Post Office 4/27/2018
113 Ice Cream   5/23/2018
19  School      7/23/2019
112 Library     3/23/2018
76  Ice Cream   6/4/2019
112 Fountain    6/10/2019
```

Here is the expected output:

```
ID  Location    Date       Group
76  School      4/12/2018  1
111 Post Office 4/15/2018  1
112 School      4/10/2018  2
324 School      2/10/2018  1
22  Library     4/12/2018  1
19  Library     4/13/2028  1 
17  Post Office 5/11/2018  1
76  Library     4/25/2018  2
19  Library     4/27/2019  2
112 School      3/23/2018  1
76  Post Office 4/27/2018  3
113 Ice Cream   5/23/2018  1
19  School      7/23/2019  1
112 Library     3/23/2018  1
76  Ice Cream   6/4/2019   4
112 Fountain    6/10/2019  3
```

The output should have a new column where it groups IDs by their first location (by date), and then the second group should be where those same people traveled next, etc.

Any help would be appreciated. I know how to load the file into python and such, but for the life of me I am having incredible amounts of trouble creating a function for the above. Again, thank you for any help!

Comment: You should look into custom sorting, save it in a list and sort it using id and date.

Comment: I did so in excel. Where I am hitting a snag is when dealing with thousand of IDs.I would have to manually assign a group by each member ID, for all five thousand, and then group all of them together. I know a function can be created in python, but am hitting a road block.

Comment: @Logan not sure I understand, why ID=112 has twice 1 in group, is it because it is the same date ID 112 went to 2 places?

Comment: @Ben.T Correct! There may be instances where an ID chooses to go to multiple places on the same day, which can cause some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer using pandas. Assuming you have the data in a csv file we can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv')
gdf = pd.DataFrame()

#Change to datetime for rank operation
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.sort_values('Date')

# Rank by date and do a dense rank to avoid same date as same rank
gdf['Rank'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].rank(method='dense')
result = df.join(gdf)

# Sort to match original order of table
result = result.sort_index()

print(result)

     ID    Location       Date  Rank
0    76      School 2018-04-12   1.0
1   111  PostOffice 2018-04-15   1.0
2   112      School 2018-04-10   2.0
3   324      School 2018-02-10   1.0
4    22     Library 2018-04-12   1.0
5    19     Library 2018-04-13   1.0
6    17  PostOffice 2018-05-11   1.0
7    76     Library 2018-04-25   2.0
8    19     Library 2019-04-27   2.0
9   112      School 2018-03-23   1.0
10   76  PostOffice 2018-04-27   3.0
11  113    IceCream 2018-05-23   1.0
12   19      School 2019-07-23   3.0
13  112     Library 2018-03-23   1.0
14   76    IceCream 2019-06-04   4.0
15  112    Fountain 2019-06-10   3.0
```

Note: I think there is a small mistake in your results for this row:

```
19  School      7/23/2019  1
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing my mistake. And thank you for the answer!

Comment: Great answer, and thanks to index alignement, you can even to if directly with `df['Rank'] = df.sort_values('Date').groupby('ID')['Date'].rank(method='dense')` without creating gdf nor sorting df before or join and sort_index after ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That does make a lot of sense and would improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a CSV dataset as you mentioned (stripped of the first line):

```
76  School      4/12/2018
111 Post Office 4/15/2018
112 School      4/10/2018
324 School      2/10/2018
22  Library     4/12/2018
19  Library     4/13/2028
17  Post Office 5/11/2018
76  Library     4/25/2018
19  Library     4/27/2019
112 School      3/23/2018
76  Post Office 4/27/2018
113 Ice Cream   5/23/2018
19  School      7/23/2019
112 Library     3/23/2018
76  Ice Cream   6/4/2019
112 Fountain    6/10/2019
```

We can then use a custom sort() to sort the data the way you want:

```
import csv
import datetime

l = []

with open('stack.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        l.append(row)


l.sort(key = lambda x: (int(x[0]), datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], '%m/%d/%Y')))
[print(i) for i in l]
```

This will give you the following output (sorted on ID and date):

```
['17', 'PO', '05/11/2018']
['19', 'L', '04/27/2019']
['19', 'S', '07/23/2019']
['19', 'L', '04/13/2028']
['22', 'L', '04/12/2018']
['76', 'S', '04/12/2018']
['76', 'L', '04/25/2018']
['76', 'IC', '06/04/2019']
['76', 'PO', '04/27/2020']
['111', 'PO', '04/15/2018']
['112', 'S', '02/23/2018']
['112', 'L', '03/23/2018']
['112', 'S', '04/10/2018']
['112', 'F', '06/10/2019']
['113', 'IC', '05/23/2018']
['324', 'S', '02/10/2018']
```

Adding group to this output could be done using a for loop:

```
f_id = l[0][0]
group = 1
for i in l:
    if f_id != i[0]:
        group = 1
        f_id = i[0]
    i.append(group)
    group+=1
```

This will get you your output:

```
['17', 'PO', '05/11/2018', 1]
['19', 'L', '04/27/2019', 1]
['19', 'S', '07/23/2019', 2]
['19', 'L', '04/13/2028', 3]
['22', 'L', '04/12/2018', 1]
['76', 'S', '04/12/2018', 1]
['76', 'L', '04/25/2018', 2]
['76', 'IC', '06/04/2019', 3]
['76', 'PO', '04/27/2020', 4]
['111', 'PO', '04/15/2018', 1]
['112', 'S', '02/23/2018', 1]
['112', 'L', '03/23/2018', 2]
['112', 'S', '04/10/2018', 3]
['112', 'F', '06/10/2019', 4]
['113', 'IC', '05/23/2018', 1]
['324', 'S', '02/10/2018', 1]
```

You can then write this list back into a CSV file with your headings

Comment: I noticed the date changed here with regards to ID 112. ID should have 03/23/2018 for both Library and School, putting that person in group 1. Otherwise, the rest looks good. Not sure how that may be resolved.

Comment: @Logan that was a typo on my end, when copying your data set I made a booboo